# Oracle EBS 12.1.3 Concurrent Job issue after 19C migration

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle19c, oracle-ebs

We have a concurrent job that started failing after migrating the Oracle Database to 19C for Oracle EBS 12.1.3.Below is the error that we get after the concurrent job failing in Oracle EBS.

Current system time is 30-NOV-2022 19:01:43

Cause: FDPSTP failed due to ORA-20100: ORA-20100: Temporary file creation for FND_FILE failed.
Directory &FILE_DIR is invalid, contact your system administrator.

Action: Check that the directory is a valid directory with wri
Start of log messages from FND_FILE
End of log messages from FND_FILE
No completion options were requested.

Output file size:
0
Deleting empty output file.
Concurrent request completed
Current system time is 30-NOV-2022 19:01:44

Answer (score 0):

With Database 19c, the UTL_FILE_DIR database initialization parameter has been desupported. As part of the upgrade to Database 19c, you must migrate all UTL_FILE_DIR database initialization parameters to database directory objects.  EBS development has created a utility to migrate and manage your defined PL/SQL file input/output directories.

You need to ensure you've followed the instructions given in Section 3.1.1 of "Using UTL_FILE_DIR or Database Directories for PL/SQL File I/O in Oracle E-Business Suite Releases 12.1 and 12.2" (Doc ID 2525754.1).

This [blog](https://www.funoracleapps.com/2021/04/upgrading-oracle-ebs-12210-database.html) also has a good description of the upgrade.