Best way to write text output to concurrent program output in EBS R12
I have a requirement where I need to write the output of a program to concurrent program output file in text format. I am on Oracle EBS R12.
It is actually a report with a large volume of data (over 200k lines for a date range). I tried using Bi Publisher with Excel output . But due to the large volume of data, the report never completes.
I tried using FND_FILE.PUT_LINE. But since there is a buffer limit for FND_FILE, this also does not work.
Any suggestions on how to go about getting the entire output of the pl/sql program into a text file via a concurrent program?

Use the Blitz Report tool. It does not have any file size limitations, users need the data in Excel anyway and there is a free version too.

Consider using the native DB UTL_FILE - you can flush to the file with UTL_FILE.FFLUSH .
There is setup needed - you'll want to create DB Directory Objects in order to allow writing to the file system.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74648514/7184001 for information on configuring these with EBS.
